# Unramified extension of a imaginary quadratic field.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic number field over $\Bbb{Q}$. Let $K(\sqrt{a})$ be an extension with $a$ an integer. Let $d$ be discriminant of field $K$. Then how to show that $K(\sqrt{a})$ is unramified over $K$ iff $a$ can be chosen so that $a$ divides $d$ and $4$ divides $a-1$? Please help.

Comment: It is not tru that this is an if and only if condition; for example, the extension $K(\sqrt{-1})/K$ is unramified over $K =  {\mathbb Q}(sqrt{-5})$.